# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS kickstart not working with nfs option in ks file

Tags: 16.04, nfs, kickstart

I'm attempting to automate some desktop installs using kickstart file instead of the preseed file. I understand that the process converts the ks.cfg file to the relevant preseed file

The error encountered after the PXE boot is in the nfs --server=a.b.c.d --dir=/path/to/ubuntu/media section of the ks file.

It keeps giving an nfs mount error. Confirmed no FW between client and nfs server.

On other virtual console, I'm also unable to mount -t nfs a.b.c.d:/path/to/ubuntu/media /mnt  - it just hangs.

I did see in /var/log/syslog (virtual console 4) a warning that says Xenial doesn't support this mirror type or something.

Is nfs server for setup of base install not supported? So it has to be via http:// or ftp:// etc?

Can someone point me to proper documentation to setup preseed file and doing automated desktop installation with some customization tips (e.g. add salt minion so I can then configure client desktop with saltstack)

Thanks,

Edit:

Here's what I did -

1. mount the ubuntu-16.04 desktop iso and copy over kernel and initrd file to pxe server. Server will pxe boot and get dhcp and then get pxelinux.0 via tftp and boot that and read the pxe file to process next steps as below
2. in /tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/

```
serial 0 115200 0x303
timeout 6000
default menu.c32
prompt 0
menu begin desktop-test

label Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop 
  kernel ks/kernel/vmlinuz-ubuntu-16.04
  append initrd=ks/kernel/initrd-ubuntu-16.04.img preseed/url=http://mirrorhost.localdomain/repo/ubuntu/preseed/ubuntu-16.04-preseed.cfg -- 
  ipappend 2
```

3. the preseed file created is :

```
d-i debian-installer/language string en
d-i debian-installer/country string US
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_US
d-i console-keymaps-at/keymap select us
d-i keyboard-configuration/xkb-keymap select us
d-i netcfg/get_hostname string unassigned-hostname
d-i netcfg/get_domain string unassigned-domain
d-i hw-detect/load_firmware boolean true
d-i mirror/country string manual
d-i mirror/http/hostname string mirror.localdomain
d-i mirror/http/directory string /repo/ubuntu
d-i mirror/http/proxy string
d-i mirror/suite string xenial
d-i passwd/root-login boolean true
d-i passwd/make-user boolean false
d-i passwd/root-password-crypted password  XXX
d-i clock-setup/utc boolean false
d-i time/zone string US/Eastern
d-i clock-setup/ntp boolean true
d-i clock-setup/ntp-server string 10.0.0.1
d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda
d-i partman-auto/method string lvm
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm_span boolean true
d-i partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
d-i partman-auto/purge_lvm_from_device boolean true
d-i partman-auto-lvm/new_vg_name string system
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/alignment string "optimal"
d-i partman-auto-lvm/guided_size string max
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string                         \
      boot-root ::                                            \
              128 100 256 ext3                                \
                      $primary{ }                             \
                      $bootable{ }                            \
                      method{ format } format{ }              \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                      mountpoint{ /boot }                     \
              .                                               \
              1024 100 8192 linux-swap                        \
                      $lvmok{ }                               \
                      $in_vg{ vg_root }                       \
                      lv_name{ lv_swap }                      \
                      method{ swap } format{ }                \
              .                                               \
              4096 100 51200 ext4                        \
                      $lvmok{ }                               \
                      $in_vg{ vg_root }                       \
                      lv_name{ lv_root }                      \
                      method{ format } format{ }              \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                      mountpoint{ / }                         \
              .
              4096 100 8192 ext4                        \
                      $lvmok{ }                               \
                      $in_vg{ vg_root }                       \
                      lv_name{ lv_var }                       \
                      method{ format } format{ }              \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                      mountpoint{ /var }                      \
              .
              1024 100 4096 ext4                        \
                      $lvmok{ }                               \
                      $in_vg{ vg_root }                       \
                      lv_name{ lv_tmp }                       \
                      method{ format } format{ }              \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                      mountpoint{ /tmp }                      \
              .
              4096 100 -1 ext4                          \
                      $lvmok{ }                               \
                      $in_vg{ vg_root }                       \
                      lv_name{ lv_extra }                     \
                      method{ format } format{ }              \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                      mountpoint{ /extra }                    \
              .
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i base-installer/install-recommends boolean false
d-i base-installer/kernel/linux/initramfs-generators string initramfs-tools
d-i apt-setup/non-free boolean true
d-i apt-setup/contrib boolean true
d-i apt-setup/services-select multiselect security
d-i apt-setup/security_host string security.debian.org
tasksel tasksel/first multiselect none
d-i pkgsel/include string openssh-server less htop vim pidgin lsb-release zip unzip ubuntu-desktop mate-desktop-environment mate-desktop-environment-extras build-essential rsh-server rsync lightdm eclipse thunderbird rdesktop qpdf subversion git synergy libreoffice mysql-workbench ntpdate
d-i pkgsel/upgrade select full-upgrade
popularity-contest popularity-contest/participate boolean false
d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean true
d-i finish-install/reboot_in_progress note
```

I guess my ques is how do I pass the preseed file to the pxelinux properly. I don't think it is getting read at all. I set language to fr and it didn't even take it.

What is the proper syntax for pxelinux.cfg/ for it to parse the debian-installer preseed file?
update w/ Ans: use url="http://webserver/preseed.cfg" in pxelinux.cfg file

Many thanks,

Comment: Are you willing to setup preseed file or continue with kickstart?

Comment: Yes, I'm willing to setup preseed file and forego kickstart route. I saw that kickstart options were limited (no ldap integration, no nfs to install base system etc.).  I did setup a preseed file but ended up with "d-i Bad package file" or error thus.              I have PXE env setup so it gets its IP/tftp kernel and boots and in my pxelinux.cfg file I've pointed it to the preseed file served over http via : append initrd=... preseed/url=http://10.x.x.x/repo/ubuntu/preseed/mypreseed.cfg

Comment: Can you post your preseed file in the question? Which media are you using for booting?

Comment: I couldn't post the whole thing due to comment length limit. I've edited my question above instead.

Comment: Sure! This is the correct way to post in StackExchange! Now people can try to help you. Comments are just for minor issues or for getting the question clearer.

Comment: I have a bad experience with Ubuntu Desktop media and preseed... Did you tried with the Server media?

Comment: This is unexpected, but Ubuntu Desktop media lacks some installation features.

Comment: I got it working to a point now but it fails on the mirror part. I want to do it from local LAN (via nfs/http via local server) similar to fedora. How can I set this up? All I want to do is have something like d-i nfs/host blah, d-i nfs/path /path/to/iso. 
Is this doable? I don't want it to go out to the internet to a mirror site.

Comment: Do you mean this preseed worked with Ubuntu Desktop media or Server media?

Comment: Sorry, to be clear - It didn't work with the Ubuntu desktop or service media. It built off of the internet - archive.ubuntu.com. 

I used debmirror to mirror the xenial release of archive.ubuntu.com to a host in my network and I get errors - Ign's and complaint that repo does not have a Release file (which it does) and some http503 errors. 

I'm aghast that ubuntu is so painful to get a setup where I just have hosts in my network build off of another local box in the network or I'm missing something (or a lot ;)

Comment: So, you have another question: How to build an Ubuntu repository? Right? Without the release file, your repo won't work. For answering the first question(preseed installation), you need a working repo...